# How to handle where clause within mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql

Here is my procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists GetID;
CREATE PROCEDURE GetID(IN tb VARCHAR(255), in name2 varchar(255))
BEGIN

set @sel = concat( 'select id FROM ', tb, ' WHERE ename = ', name2);
prepare stmt from @sel;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried to execute the stored procedure by using GetID('city', 'ny'). I got an error

> unknown column 'ny' in where clause ...

Here 'city' is the table name. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that name2 is a string parameter which to be compared with ename column of the passed table

Put quotes around name2 in the SQL:

```
set @sel = concat('select id FROM ', tb, ' WHERE ename = ''', name2,'''');
```

It's usually recommended not to use string concatenation to build SQL queries. Since you are hardcoding the column name in the query, it makes little sense to provide the table name "dynamically". But, if you must, use `QUOTE` to properly escape and quote the passed string.

```
set @sel = concat('select id FROM ', tb, ' WHERE ename = ', quote(name2));
```

Comment: It works! Could you explain why I should put triple quotes after 'ename=' and four quotes at the end? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out why I need triple quotes  after 'ename=' and four quotes at the end. Suppose the query should look like this,  'select id from tb where ename='name2''. If we need escape the single quote by using one more quote, it should look like 'select id from tb where ename=''name2'''. What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nooooooo.  SQL injection fail.

Comment: @dullboy - three quotes after ename - two quotes to actually type one and other to escape it and third to close the string.  At the very last, 4 quotes - two quotes are start and end of string and the middle two types one quote.

Answer (score 1):

Never concatenate strings directly into queries.  It's bad enough that you're passing a table name in, unsanitized.  That needs to be fixed, too, but one correct solution to your immediate issue is this:

```
set @sel = concat( 'select id FROM ', tb, ' WHERE ename = ', QUOTE(name2));
```

The `QUOTE()` function *correctly* and safely quotes and escapes the argument, and also handles null values correctly... and prevents a SQL injection vulnerability here.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote.